# Reformatting a string of numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, formatting

In our application we have a string of digits (stored as a String) for a registration number (Australian Business Number or Australian Company Number, similar to a SSN), for example:

```
"98123123999"
```

When we display this information in our web application it would be nice to be able to reformat the digits to be more readable, e.g.:

```
98 123 123 999
```

In ruby the best solution I have so far is to:

1. Check the length
2. Format the string by using the slice operator: `[a[0,2], a[2,3], a[5,3], a[8, 3]].join(" ")`

However this smells and doesn't seem right.

Whats the best way to do something seemingly so simple?

Edit: I should note as well that the string of numbers could be prefixed with a 0 (e.g. "012345678901") so it isn't possible to parse it as an integer then use format strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
a = "98123123999"
=> "98123123999" 
b = a.split('').insert(2, ' ').insert(6, ' ').insert(10, ' ')
=> "9", "8", " ", "1", "2", "3", " ", "1", "2", "3", " ", "9", "9", "9"] 
b = a.split('').insert(2, ' ').insert(6, ' ').insert(10, ' ').join
=> "98 123 123 999"
```

or if u want the string to be modified

```
a = "98123123999"
=> "98123123999" 
b = a.insert(2, ' ').insert(6, ' ').insert(10, ' ')
=> "98 123 123 999" 
a
=> "98 123 123 999"
```

Comment: Thats perfect, and seems pretty efficient. Given the strings are transient modification is not an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For a more generic point of view, if you use rails, you can use [`number_with_delimiter(number, delimiter=",", separator=".")`](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M000369).

Otherwise, maybe just write something based on its [source code](https://gist.github.com/484764).

```
number.to_s.gsub!(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/, "\\1#{' '}")

>> 1234567890.to_s.gsub!(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/, "\\1#{' '}")
=> "1 234 567 890"
```

Comment: suppose i have a number 1234512345. i want it to be displayed as '12345 12345'. how can i use the number_with_delimiter method here. an example would be really good.

Comment: @surase.prasad Edited my answer. You just replace the 3 with the 5 and you are good to go.

Comment: Umm, any reason why you interpolate a space into a string instead just writing `"\\1 "`?

Comment: @MladenJablanović Just follower the rails source code. Did not try to improve or change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def format_digit(s, acc="")
  if s.size > 3
    new_acc = s[-3..-1] + " " +acc
    format_digit(s[0...-3], new_acc)
  else
    s + " " + acc
  end
end

s = "98123123999"
puts format_digit(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this suits your needs cause the group of two digits comes in the end instead of the beginning...

```
"98123123999".scan(/.{1,3}/).join(' ') #=> "981 231 239 99"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str           = "098123123999"
formatted_arr = []

if str.length % 3 == 0
    (str.length/3).times { formatted_arr << str.slice!(0..2) }
else
    formatted_arr << str.slice!(0..str.length % 3 - 1)
    (str.length/3).times { formatted_arr << str.slice!(0..2) }
end

puts formatted_arr.join(" ") # 098 123 123 999
```